# How I can I query the IP address of a local network name

Tags: networking, dns

I'm at a hackerspace and they have an internal web server available at `http://foobar:1234`  Notice there is no root suffix.

Unfortunately for me, I have my DNS set to some external DNS server which means `foobar` does not resolve.

Without changing my DNS settings, how can I query the IP address of `foobar`.

### What I tried:

I tried checking the gateway my machine is connected to. It's `10.20.0.1`. On the off chance the space's DNS server is there I tried

```
dig @10.20.0.1 foobar
```

It didn't fail but it did not return an IP address for `foobar`

```
; <<>> DiG 9.10.6 <<>> @10.20.0.1 foobar
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 27399
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;foobar.            IN  A

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
.           86257   IN  SOA a.root-servers.net. nstld.verisign-grs.com. 2022091601 1800 900 604800 86400

;; Query time: 25 msec
;; SERVER: 10.20.0.1#53(10.21.0.1)
;; WHEN: Fri Sep 16 17:29:57 PDT 2022
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 114
```

I'm not even sure it's the correct DNS server.

Running `ipconfig getpacket en0` got me

```
op = BOOTREPLY
htype = 1
flags = 0
hlen = 6
hops = 0
xid = 0x1e9811a7
secs = 0
ciaddr = 0.0.0.0
yiaddr = 10.20.1.66
siaddr = 10.20.0.1
giaddr = 0.0.0.0
chaddr = f0:3f:5b:12:7c:8f
sname = 
file = 
options:
Options count is 11
dhcp_message_type (uint8): ACK 0x5
server_identifier (ip): 10.20.0.1
lease_time (uint32): 0xa8c0
renewal_t1_time_value (uint32): 0x5460
rebinding_t2_time_value (uint32): 0x93a8
subnet_mask (ip): 255.255.0.0
broadcast_address (ip): 10.20.255.255
domain_name (string): noise
domain_name_server (ip_mult): {10.20.0.1, 1.1.1.1}
router (ip_mult): {10.20.0.1}
end (none):
```

So it seems like 10.20.0.1 the DNS server I'd get if I didn't have mine set to a custom DNS

What commands will tell me the address of `foobar` without changing my DNS settings?

Comment: You must know ip of dns server in advance.

Comment: @gapsf You're right. Yet usually people don't have to enter them manually. That's because DHCP provides the DNS server's address in advance. This is what OP tried to check with `ipconfig getpacket`.

Comment: Scan subnet for more dns servers

Comment: Why not temporarly switch to their dns server with dhcp?

Answer (score 1):

According to your ifconfig output, `10.20.0.1` is the server, and `noise` is the domain suffix you must add to unqualified names:

```
dig foobar.noise @10.20.0.1
```